# How to load external css using require in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, css, angular, webpack, styles

I need to load an external css file in environment files. I have two environments: **dev** and **prod**. It works well in mode dev because the css file is in local, but not in mode prod.

**environment.dev.ts**

```
require("style-loader!./../assets/style.css");
```

**environment.prod.ts**

```
require("style-loader!http://abc/style.css");
```

Then i had this error:

> Can't resolve 'http://abc/sprite.css'

How could i make it work with url ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE**

As the suggestion of Milad, i try to put a link with the dynamic *href*:

```
<link [attr.href]="getCss()" type="text/css">

function getCss(): string {
    return this.mode === 'dev' ?
        'assets/style.css':
        'http://abc/sprite.css';
}
```

And i have the following error:

> unsafe value used in a resource URL context

Comment: What are you trying to do here ? You usualy don't have to load from an url as webpack is a bundler, it will include the path in the bundle and hte stylesheets gets added to the html it as a relative url...

Comment: Also, http://abc/style.css returns 404..

Comment: @GiliYaniv yes, it's not the real link, i just want to show it is an external link

Comment: @n00dl3 the problem is in dev mode, i want to use, let's say path-1; in prod mode i want another path. How could i do that ?

Comment: OK, the real question is "does this css file exists at build time at this url ?" If it does exist, you can just use the [resolve-url-loader](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader) (it sounds like a weird idea, but maybe that's legit). If it doesn't, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Yeah, it think you are right. I also prefer to check if the css file exists at runtime. I tried to do that but ended up with another problem. I updated my question with the new error. Thanks !

Comment: this is not my solution, I said download the css and use it in normal way

Comment: The problem is the css is not always the same, it changes from time to time (in fact, it belongs to another service). But i figured out how to fix this problem by using DomSanitizer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have http calls in your webpack's loader configuration because technically that loader does not exist in your production environment.

so

```
  require("style-loader!http://abc/style.css");
```

What you're saying is :

Hey webpack, when you're building my app, call this url and get the css and include it in the bundle.

This shouldn't work because `Webpack` shouldn't make an external call to get your bundle pieces.

Try downloading the css and putting it in your code .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution and updated my question with a new error: "unsafe value used in a resource URL context"

Comment: I fixed this bug by using DomSanitizer. Thank you anyway !